# Calculate area weighted mean values of polygons for raster cells using R

Tags: r, sf, rasterization, terra, stars

#### Problem

I want to rasterize polygon values and assign their weighted mean to raster cells.
Weighting should be done based on the polygons' cell coverage.

#### Problem visualized

[image: polgyon_raster]

**Calculation for grid cell II**

- Polygon A covers 10% of II.
- Polygon B covers 25% of II.
- Total polygon coverage of II is 35%.

So the value assigned for grid cell II will be:

```
(0.1/0.35)*5 + (0.25/0.35)*2 = 2.857
```

For grid cells I, III and IV it’s easy: They only get covered by one polygon and get their respective polgon's value assigned.

#### Reproducible Example

```
library("dplyr")
library("sf")
library("stars")
library("ggplot2")

nc_sf <- system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf") %>% 
  st_read() %>% 
  select(BIR74) %>% 
  rename(values = "BIR74")
nc_sf
# Simple feature collection with 100 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
# Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
# First 10 features:
#   values                       geometry
# 1    1091 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...
# 2     487 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3...
# 3    3188 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3...
# 4     508 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3...
# 5    1421 MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.21767 3...

nc_stars <- st_as_stars(
  st_bbox(nc_sf),
  nx = 20,
  ny = 10
  ) %>% 
  .[nc_sf] 
nc_stars
# stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
# attribute(s):
#   Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max. NA's
# values     0       0      0    0       0    0   91
# dimension(s):
#   from to   offset     delta refsys point values x/y
# x    1 20 -84.3239  0.443344  NAD27    NA   NULL [x]
# y    1 10  36.5896 -0.270766  NAD27    NA   NULL [y]
# Error in find.package(if (is.null(package)) loadedNamespaces() else package,  : 
#   there is no package called ‘extactextract’
# > nc_sf
# Simple feature collection with 100 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
# Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
# First 10 features:
#    values                       geometry
# 1    1091 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...
# 2     487 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3...
# 3    3188 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3...
# 4     508 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3...
# 5    1421 MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.21767 3...
# 6    1452 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.74506 3...
# 7     286 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3...
# 8     420 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.56251 3...
# 9     968 MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.30876 3...
# 10   1612 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.02567 3...
```

```
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = nc_sf, 
          aes(fill = values)) +
  ggtitle("polygons with values to be rasterized")

ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = st_geometry(nc_sf)) +
  geom_stars(data = nc_stars, alpha = 0.8) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ggtitle("target raster")
```

[image: polgons]
[image: target_raster]

#### Ideas on potential solutions

```
# Potentially helpful packages and functions
library("stars")
library("exactextractr")
library("terra")
library("raster")

stars::st_rasterize()
exactextractr::coverage_fraction()
terra::rasterize()
raster::rasterize()
```

I would prefer a [`stars::st_rasterize()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stars/vignettes/stars5.html) based solution, but I'm happy to bring in other packages and functions such as [`exactextractr::coverage_fraction()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exactextractr/readme/README.html) or [`terra::rasterize()`](https://rdrr.io/github/rspatial/terra/man/rasterize.html) or the [`raster`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html) package. These seem to be the most promising to me.

My real life problem raster is pretty fine grained (around 690 000 cells), so I definitely need a solution that's not too computationally expensive. Hence, I'm afraid turning my raster into a polgyons to do all the calculations in `sf` is not really viable.

Comment: Where does that `"there is no package called ‘extactextract’"` message come from? It looks like a typo for `exactextract` (look carefully, its "extact-" at the start) and there's no mention of that in the code, so, is that in one of the packages?? Note you also need `dplyr` for the `rename` function.

Comment: fixed it @Spacedman, thx for pointing out the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more classic variation on Aldo's approach

Eexample data

```
library(terra)
nc <- vect(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
r <- rast(nc, ncol=20, nrow=10, crs=crs(nc))
```

Solution (using extract, but you can use exactextractr for better performance)

```
r <- init(r, NA)
e <- extract(r, nc, exact=TRUE, cells=TRUE) 
e$value <- nc$BIR74[e$ID] * e$fraction
a <- aggregate(e[, c("value", "fraction")], e[,"cell", drop=FALSE], sum)
r[a$cell] <- a$value / a$fraction

r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 20, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.4433437, 0.2707657  (x, y)
#extent      : -84.32385, -75.45698, 33.88199, 36.58965  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat NAD27 (EPSG:4267) 
#source      : memory 
#name        :    lyr.1 
#min value   : 296.3705 
#max value   : 17557.43
```

Comment: This is great - thank you Robert! I had no idea this would require so few lines of code...

Answer (score 4):

`exactextractr` gives you the information you need:

Get pixel's xy cordinates and coverage fraction per pixel by polygon:

```
library(exactextractr)
library(terra)

result <- exact_extract(rast(nc_stars), nc_sf, include_xy = T)
```

Add `values` by polygon and join all to a unique data.frame:

```
nc_values <- nc_sf %>% st_drop_geometry() %>% select(values)

for(i in seq_along(result)){
  result[[i]] <- cbind(result[[i]],values = nc_values[i,])
}

result <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,result)
```

This looks something like:

```
head(result)
# value         x        y coverage_fraction values
# 1    NA -81.88546 36.45427        0.07680427   1091
# 2     0 -81.44212 36.45427        0.76939684   1091
# 3     0 -81.44212 36.18350        0.10582609   1091
# 4     0 -81.44212 36.45427        0.13069978    487
# 5     0 -80.99877 36.45427        0.38078466    487
# 6     0 -80.99877 36.45427        0.30874124   3188
```

Then create new fields for getting the following:

```
(0.1/0.35)*5 + (0.25/0.35)*2 = 2.857
sum( (coverage_fraction/pixel_cov_fraction) * values)
```

Where `pixel_cov_fraction` is the sum of all polygons' `coverage_fraction`:

```
result %>% group_by(x, y) %>% 
  mutate(pixel_cov_fraction = sum(coverage_fraction),
         frac_value = values * coverage_fraction/pixel_cov_fraction) %>% 
  summarise(final_value = sum(frac_value, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ungroup() -> for_raster
```

Looks like:

```
head(for_raster)
# # A tibble: 6 × 3
# x        y           final_value
# <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 -84.1  35.1        972.
# 2 -84.1  35.4        514.
# 3 -84.1  35.6        675 
# 4 -83.7  35.1        621.
# 5 -83.7  35.4        588.
# 6 -83.7  35.6        675
```

Then, rasterize results:

```
coords <- as.matrix(for_raster[,c('x','y')])

r <- rasterize(x = coords, y = rast(nc_stars),
               values = for_raster$final_value)

plot(r)
```

[image]

Comment: You can remove the "Add values by polygon" step with the `include_cols` argument to `exact_extract`

Comment: @dbaston yes, I have used that argument many times. For some reason, `include_cols` failed with the example given: `In format.data.frame(if (omit) x[seq_len(n0), , drop = FALSE] else x,  ... : corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs`